# register (regsvr32) 2 dll files with activex

Tags: dll, activex, dllregistration

Is this possible ? When I access an web page with internet explorer I want to register 2 dll if they are not available, is this possible ? I don`t know much about Microsoft Programming Languages/ Script Languages. If It is possible, please direct me to some relevant links.

I want to register 2 .dll files that usually I register using regsvr32. The 2 files are decoders for an unusual video format  coming from a mobile camera ( installed on a car )

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clarify your question. Are you trying to *install* an ActiveX control from a webpage? If so, ensure that the control supports DllRegisterServer, it's digitally signed, and its download URL is referenced in the CODEBASE attribute of the OBJECT tag.